# Calling revert on jQuery draggable after it is dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating a simple draggable div with drag and drop functionality using jQuery UI.
After the div is dropped on one of several targets, I am calling a function to see if this target is correct. I need this to be a function, because the conditions are different each time a div is dropped.

My question: how can I call the "revert" effect even after the "drop" function is evaluated?
Just calling ".revert()" doesn't do anything.

```
// 
// a draggable block
//
$(".textblock").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    stack: ".textblock",
    stop: function(e,ui) {
        //
    },
    // reverts when not dropped in the right div
    revert: "invalid"
});

//
// evaluate the drop target after div is dropped
//
$(".icon").droppable({
    hoverClass: "hovering",
    tolerance: "fit",

    drop: function(e,ui) {
        // if some condition is false, revert the div to original position
        // in the same way as when the div was dragged outside the droppable?
        // revert() doesnt work
        if(someCondition == false) ui.draggable.revert();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for so many edits, I got it right this time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you wanna use the **droppable accept** JQuery UI feature.

It allows you to do something like this:

```
$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ".draggable"
});
```

With droppable class you can define which elements are not invalid.

Comment: This doesn't work because the condition changes after the html and jquery is initialized. I need to evaluate the drop target at the moment the draggable is dropped.